Can Windows Edge/Chrome/Firefox do Kerberos Negotiate (not NTLM)?
I am able to succesfully kinit + klist to verify a ticket on Mac + Windows. I even carried over my Kerberos configuration to "KerberosForWindows".
It does not seem that any browser on Windows can do Kerberos style Negotiate instead of Windows-style NTLM. Is that the case?
I've tried all of the Local Site / Intranet / Trusted Domain / browser config propagate domain for negotiation auth. I just want to confirm if Windows browsers can do GSSAPI-style Negotiate.
// Kerberos authentication middleware
async function kerberosAuth(req, res, next) {
  // Check for the Authorization header and extract the token
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Negotiate ')) {
      res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Negotiate');
      return res.status(401).send('Kerberos authentication required');
  }
  const token = authHeader.slice('Negotiate '.length);

  // Base64 decode the token
  const decodedToken = Buffer.from(token, 'base64');

  // Check if it's NTLM
  if (decodedToken.toString('hex').startsWith('4e544c4d')) {
    // always hit on Windows
    return res.status(500).send('NTLM is not supported. Please use Kerberos authentication.');
  } else {
    // only ever hit on Mac/Linux
  }


Kerberos over HTTP Negotiate is also very much "Windows-style", as the HTTP mechanism was invented by Microsoft and is defined to use MS-SPNEGO (thus the name 'Negotiate') rather than raw Kerberos tokens.
All popular browsers support Kerberos via HTTP Negotiate on Windows, but the MIT "Kerberos for Windows" package (gssapi.dll) is only supported by Mozilla/Firefox/Thunderbird, whereas IE and Chrome/Edge support Kerberos only through the Windows built-in SSPI interface (which is also the default in Firefox).
For that reason, I generally avoid installing KfW on workstations and configure Windows SSPI instead, as that gives GSSAPI support to a much longer list of software.

(If the realm is not an AD domain) Mark the realm as "MIT realm" so that Windows won't expect its KDCs to answer Netlogon pings. Skip this for Active Directory realms.
sudo ksetup /SetRealmFlags EXAMPLE.COM TcpSupported

Actual flags are optional; the presence of the realm entry in itself is what indicates the realm type being non-AD.

(If the realm is not an AD domain and someone was too lazy to add DNS SRV records) Manually define the KDC hostname.
sudo ksetup /AddKdc EXAMPLE.COM foo.example.com

Properly managed realms (both MIT and AD) should have _kerberos._udp.<domain> SRV records pointing at the KDCs and won't need this configuration. Note that the presence of this entry marks it as a MIT/non-AD realm, as above.

(If the client uses a local account for Windows logon) Store the Kerberos credentials in the Windows Credential Manager:
cmdkey /add:*.example.com /user:foo@EXAMPLE.COM /pass

For non-domain logons, this is the closest thing SSPI has to correspond to kinit, and it will automatically acquire a TGT using stored credentials when a program tries to obtain a service ticket.
If credentials for a TGT are not available, IE and Edge/Chrome will prompt for them using a Basic-style dialog, but Firefox doesn't support that (as that's generally not something GSSAPI applications do).


Side note: Current Firefox versions have a bug where they're unable to use Kerberos via SSPI when DoH is enabled in-browser. Make sure to disable it in Firefox settings.


Make sure your credentials are stored for the correct host name. Unlike MIT Kerberos/KfW, native Windows Kerberos doesn't perform canonicalization (neither rDNS nor CNAME), so if you visit http://foo, that becomes the SPN HTTP/foo, not HTTP/foo.example.com – and therefore you need to store credentials specifically for foo; it is not enough to store them for *.example.com.

For the same reason, make sure the realm has the correct SPN in the first place. Use Wireshark or watch your KDC's logs to see what is being requested.

Instead of saved credentials, try to launch the browser using runas which puts them in the "logon session" (as if it had been a domain logon):
runas /u:foo@EXAMPLE.COM /netonly cmd

Then launch Firefox or any other Kerberos-capable client from this Cmd window (I don't think this will work with Chrome/Edge though).

Run klist get <spn> and check if a ticket for that principal shows up in the resulting list. (Make sure you're running the Windows built-in klist, not the KfW klist or Java klist!)
PS C:\>  where.exe klist
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-21.0.3.9-hotspot\bin\klist.exe
C:\Windows\System32\klist.exe
PS C:\>  C:\Windows\System32\klist get HTTP/foo.example.com


For Firefox, visit about:logging and enable logging for the negotiateauth:5 module.
(Alternatively, put that in the NSPR_LOG_MODULES environment variable, and either set NSPR_LOG_FILE as well, or run Firefox with -console.)

For IE and Edge/Chrome, manually add your hostnames or *.example.com to the "Local Intranet" zone, and make sure "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone" is chosen.

Call SSPI directly, bypassing all browser-specific logic:

Get Python 3.12 from the MS Store
pip install pyspnego or pip install sspilib
Open the interactive Python REPL and:
import spnego
ctx = spnego.client(hostname="foo.example.com",
                    service="HTTP",
                    protocol="negotiate")
out_token = ctx.step(None)

or
import sspilib
creds = sspilib.UserCredential(usage="initiate",
                               protocol="Negotiate",
                               protocol_list=["!ntlm"])
ctx = sspilib.ClientSecurityContext(credential=creds,
                                    target_name="HTTP/foo.example.com")
out_token = ctx.step(none)

or
import sspi
ctx = sspi.ClientAuth("Negotiate", targetspn="HTTP/foo.example.com")
err, bufs = ctx.authorize(None)
out_token = bufs[0].Buffer

...and verify that it returns a Kerberos token in out_token.





Chrome/Edge support Kerberos only through the Windows built-in SSPI interface (which is also the default in Firefox).

To clarify, does the Windows machine using Chrome/Edge need to be joined to a Samba domain? aka I can't use slapd (LDAP) and krb5 individually WITHOUT joining the PC to the domain?

No, it doesn't need that. Windows has always supported using Kerberos from a non-joined client (although "joined or not" is a separate matter from "AD vs non-AD Kerberos"). Instructions for using SSPI Kerberos from non-joined clients and/or with a non-Active-Directory realm are already in the post.

Whether I join or not, when I go to Edge or Chrome, after following all the steps to allow the credentials to pass from the domain, it 100% always tries NTLM and fails. My HTTP server is saying WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, it sends an NTLM token. I don't want NTLM token. Why is it trying NTLM first? How can I make it try NTLM 2nd or not at all? I want it to send non-NTLM Negotiate. I can't figure out how to trigger it / why this is happening.

By default SSPI is not trying NTLM first – it's trying Kerberos first, but failing to produce a token, then trying NTLM second (which never fails). Either it wasn't able to obtain a TGT (e.g. KDC not found, credentials missing), or it wasn't able to obtain a service ticket (e.g. wrong FQDN). Start with looking at Wireshark packet capture, if that doesn't reveal anything then there's a way to enable Kerberos debug logging in Lsass (or two ways IIRC).

I would also suggest removing the browser from the equation first: Install Python and use its sspi/sspilib/spnego modules to bypass any browser logic and directly get tickets and make tokens, to make sure that part works on its own.

I got around this by going to credentials manager and manually adding the credentials, but now it is defaulting to rc4-hmac somewhere, trying to track that down... Any guesses? samba-ad-dc from Linux

Does your user account have AES keys? Does the krbtgt account have AES keys? (It might not if the realm dates to like Samba 4.3 or so.) And does the service account have AES keys and the corresponding flags set in the msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes LDAP attribute? (The attribute is not needed for the client user, but for the service account it informs the AD KDC that the service supports AES so it's okay to issue AES tickets.) Checking klist should show whether it's just the service ticket that is RC4 or whether the TGT is RC4 as well.

I got it all working, thanks. Let me ask one more thing... If the Windows PC using the browser (the client to the "DC server" if you will), no matter what you do, it will not act is if it was joined domain wise. I have everything working with domain joined. As soon as you leave the domain, it refuses to go down Negotiate path despite having credentials and flag it like you said. Would you expect this?

No, I wouldn't expect that – I'm currently using Kerberos to both my work AD realm and my personal MIT realm from a machine that has never been joined to any of them; all I did was pre-save credentials for every matching hostname. (Note that Windows does not use rDNS or any other canonicalization, so http://foo will be looking up a ticket for HTTP/foo – not for HTTP/foo.example.com – so I had to manually save creds for the bare foo in addition to *.example.com.) The ksetup flags are only necessary for non-AD realms (where the KDCs can't answer the AD-specific "Netlogon pings").

I've updated the post with a few suggestions. For what it's worth, I'm also successfully using SSPI Kerberos with IMAP in Thunderbird, with OpenSSH (the built-in Windows ssh.exe), with Windows SMB file sharing, all from a non-domain-joined machine; it worked in WinXP and it still works in Win11.
